# How can I install System.Console.Readline for Haskell GHCi on Windows?

Tags: windows, haskell, readline

I am trying to run a haskell file from command prompt. I get the following error :

```
Failed to load interface for `System.Console.Readline'
Perhaps you meant System.Console.Haskeline (from haskeline-0.7.2.3)
Locations searched:

System\Console\Readline.hs
System\Console\Readline.lhs
System\Console\Readline.hsig
System\Console\Readline.lhsig
```

I thought readline came as part of cabal when you installed the full version of haskell? (which I have done) Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

EDIT: I tried >cabal update, followed by >cabal install readline, and I now get this:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring readline-1.0.3.0...
Failed to install readline-1.0.3.0
Build log ( C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\readline-1.0.3.0.log ):
Configuring readline-1.0.3.0...
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
checking for gcc... C:\PROGRA~1\HASKEL~1\802E01~1.1\mingw\bin\gcc.exe
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether C:\PROGRA~1\HASKEL~1\802E01~1.1\mingw\bin\gcc.exe accepts -g... yes
checking for C:\PROGRA~1\HASKEL~1\802E01~1.1\mingw\bin\gcc.exe option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for GNUreadline.framework... checking for readline... no
checking for tputs in -lncurses... no
checking for tputs in -ltermcap... no
checking for tputs in -lcurses... no
checking for rl_readline_version... no
configure: error: readline not found, so this package cannot be built
See `config.log' for more details.
cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\Users\Dan\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-884\readline-1.0.3.0'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
readline-1.0.3.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Comment: Did you end up finding a fix for this? I'm having the exact same issue.